# What are the purposes of slits inside a spectrometer (Czerny-Turner)?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, experimental-technique, experimental-technology, raman-spectroscopy

[image: Czerny-Turner Configuration]

I am building a Raman spectrometer with a Czerny Turner configuration (with RamanPi).

1. Why does the light source (A) appear to be converging into the entrance slit (B)? When a sample is excited by a laser, the Raman scattering from the sample should be diverging away from the sample. Is a converging lens typically placed in front of B to focus the light at the slit?
2. In another configuration involving a linear CCD, the exit slit is replaced by the CCD. What is the purpose of the exit slit then (F)?

[image: Linear CCD configuration]
<sub>(source: [bwtek.com](http://bwtek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/4-1.gif))</sub>

Comment: 1) Like you said, the light source (or the light from the sample) would be focused onto the entrance slit with a collimator, which is simply not shown, to enhance the brightness of the spectrum. 2) If you don't have a spatially resolving detector like the CCD, then you select one frequency and scan the spectrum one line at a time. This is what old instruments would have done (think mechanical plotter!). Today one will try to speed up the measurement by collecting the data from as many wavelengths as possible at the same time.

Comment: @CuriousOne According to wikipedia, "the slit is placed at the effective focus of a curved mirror (C) so that the light from the slit reflected from the mirror is collimated (focused at infinity)". Let call the new focusing mirror A' such that is placed some distance before the entrance slit, B. A' should also be focusing the Raman scattering exactly at B. Does this mean that A' has the negated focal length of the collimating mirror C?

Comment: Mirror C makes sure that the wavefront hitting the grating is flat (i.e. the beam is parallel). A collimating mirror would try to collect as much light as possible on the entrance slit. How much light the instrument can collect, depends on the focal length of C, though. If it is short, it collects light from wider angles than with a long focal length, very similar to a camera lens. I have to admit, though, that I never spent any time on figures of merit of spectrometers, but I would think that shorter is better and much harder to implement without losing resolution.

Comment: One good way of learning about the reality of instruments is to go to manufacturer websites. This one http://www.horiba.com/us/en/scientific/products/optics-tutorial/monochromators-spectrographs/#c3770 has some collection of facts and formulas that seem important for instrument performance. Numerical aperture, as I suspected, is one of the key performance characteristics of a real instrument.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should use external optics with a monochromator. Outside the setup you should have a lens that focuses collimated the light on to slit A. This is the reason for the converging beams. Note that, for maximum throughout you should choose a focal length focusing lens that matches the numerical aperture of the monochromator.
2. With different wavelengths now dispersed across the exit slit, the width of the slits controls the bandwidth of the "monochromated" light. By slightly rotating the grating different wavelengths will pass through the narrow slits. With that background we can now discuss your second point.

   It is usual to have a photodetector at the exit slit. This allows you to convert the light intensity for a specific wavelength to an electrical signal. However an alternative configuration is to have a CCD array at the exit. This allows one shot detection of a whole spectrum because the intensity of light falling across the surface of the array can be mapped backwards to spectrum using an appropriate transfer function.